# 175 FC-TY301 crank set upgrade

Tags: crankset

Im a newbie to the MTB scene, I have a trek bike that has a Shimano 175 FC-TY301 crankset. Today the pedal has come loose and flogged out one of the cranks. While I'm going, what's a good crank upgrade for this that will just go straight into the current housing without having to make any modifications.

I'm in Brisbane if that has any bearing on recommendations.(availability etc)

Cheers if you can help at all. Don't want to be buying parts and them not fitting and wasting money.

Comment: Given you're in Brisbane, consider checking out Turnstyle  at http://turnstyle.org.au/pigglywiggly/cycling/ and other info at  https://www.bikecollectives.org/wiki/index.php?title=Turnstyle
There's a fair chance they can help with donor parts for cheap.

Comment: Just wanted to know which one did u go fore as ive got similar problem.. product name n links 0plz

Answer (score 3):

On a Shimano Tourney equipped bike I would not bother upgrading much. You could put an Altus, Acera or Alvio crank on but there is no point going beyond that.

The TY301 fits on a cartridge square taper also bottom bracket. Altus, Acera and Alvio ranges all have triple crank that fit on such a BB. The trick is that different cranks need a different length BB axle to get the right chainline. What you'll need to do is match the new crank to your current BB - OR - get a new BB with the new crank.

Shimano makes this really easy by publishing all the compatibility information. The [FC-TY301 page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/product/component/tourney/FC-TY301.html) lists the BB's it is compatible with, you can look up other cranks specs here https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc.

Answer (score 2):

Argenti's answer has the necessary information. I'll offer a link to [Shimano's compatibility tech document](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?acid=C-449&cid=C-432) where in the section, "Separate Type FC-BB" (that's Front Chainwheel-Bottom Bracket), is listed several models of crankset that would be a drop in replacement for yours.  In order to just swap cranksets without messing with the bottom bracket, you'd choose from the square taper cranks that have the same BB as your current one.  It appears the highest level for drop in replacement is the Acera-class, FC-M3010.  Price points are within $20 USD.