# Shimano 170mm FC-TY301 48/38/28 alternative

Tags: shimano

I have a Marin Fairfax 2 bike and I’m new to biking. When the bike was assembled the right pedal was not properly put in and came off.it has ruined the threads on the crankshaft right arm.

I would like to replace the crank which is a Shimano 170mm FC-TY301 48/38/28. However, I cannot find this crank as it is out of stock everywhere. Is there an alternative I could use?

Comment: Not a dupe, but relevant  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66120/175-fc-ty301-crank-set-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FC-TY501 is a straight swap according to Shimano's specs https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/tourney/3x7, but you will need to get one the same chainrings you have now (e.g. 48/38/28 or 42/34/24).

Other options will work fine also, preferably those with 47.5mm chainline, but for proper front shifting either matching all three chainrings, or failing that smaller chainrings with the same gap and then move your front derailleur up/down, will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The specs are published at https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/tourney/FC-TY301.html   so you need a triple chainring crankarm, with 170mm long crank, and probably a square-taper bottom bracket fitting.

While "matching the chainline" is important, its likely that any similar part will fit up and work fine, with perhaps some minimal tweaking of the front derailleur.

Your other options are to

1. try chasing the remaining threads with a 9/16-20tpi right-hand tap.  Though if they're all gone then this isn't going to work.
2. fit a thread-repair insert, but again this requires enough "meat" to hold the new threads.  And the 20tpi version is hard to find.  Don't use the common 18tpi version, that won't match your pedals.

Don't take it wrong, but tourney is about the lowest "grade" of shimano product, so don't spend a lot on it.